# change brew installation location to /usr/local

Tags: terminal, homebrew

Trying to install python3 with `brew install python3`. Prior to this I have added and sourced the ~/.zshrc file (created by me, it was absent by default) containing:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
(OR)
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

But the output of `which python3` is always `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`. I would like to have the output as `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Immediately after the installation of brew I ran the following commands as it was instructed in the terminal

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

I also tried uninstalling brew and then a fresh installation followed by not running the above commands but the output of `which python3` is same

Comment: How did you get python3 into /usr/local/bin? Is your machine Apple Silicon or Intel? What is your default shell? Why are you running the last set of commands?

Comment: I didn't get the python3 into /usr/local, I would like to have it that way. My Chip is Apple M1 pro and my shell is zsh (The prompt starts with % ). The last set of commands I had to run as it was instructed when I installed brew

Comment: What do you want to say with "I have both runned and didn't run" in your last sentence?

Comment: @nohillside edited the question, my bad should have explained better.

Comment: Where is your python executable?

Comment: Executables are in desktop but the reason I want to do it was to create python virtual environments and I have managed to do it without changing the installation location. Thanks for reaching out!

Comment: The edit totally changed the question ;-) Is there a python3 in /usr/local/bin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On ARM Macs, Homebrew will always install to `/opt/homebrew` and put its binaries into `/opt/homebrew/bin`. So you need to adjust your PATH to include `/opt/homebrew/bin` as well.

An easy way to set all relevant PATHs is to run

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv
```

and add the result to the init file of your choice.